# Why can't I shuffle songs within a specific album under the latest version of iTunes 12.5.1.21?

Tags: itunes, music

Prior to the update, I was able to select the "Shuffle Songs" button in the upper-mid Information Bar, click on a specific song in an album and then hear a mix of songs **only** from that album.

For example: If I clicked on a song from the album *L.A. Woman* and I had shuffle enabled, I would only hear other songs from that album.

Under the current version, If I select a song from *L.A Woman*, I will get that one song and then a mix of songs from my entire library.

In this example, the next song might be from *Frank Sinatra*, the *Dead Kennedys*, or anything else.

**How do I disable this "feature?"**

**I don't want to have to click "Shuffle Album" to hear the songs shuffled.**

Often I will start with one song I want to hear, hear another song from the random shuffle on the album, and then select a new song to hear from the same album

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Control > Shuffle
In the drop down/slide out menu check 'Album' instead of 'Songs'